# Is $x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{1+y}\right)$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

My question is the function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ convex where

$$f(x,y)=x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{1+y}\right).$$

I have found the partial derivatives as follow:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}=0.$$
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=\dfrac{x(3+2y)}{(1+y)^2(2+y)^2}.$$
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}=-\dfrac{1}{(1+y)(2+y)}.$$

But I cannot continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $y \mapsto \ln(1+ {1 \over 1+y} )$ is not convex for $y<2$,
hence $f$ is not convex on $\{1\} \times (-\infty, -2)$.

Comment: Why do you have the singleton $\{1\}$? $f(x, \cdot)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$ no?

Comment: If $f$ is not convex on some convex subset, then it is not convex. I just picked the half line above as an example. $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is not convex on $\mathbb{R}$. Just plot it.